# MYSQL - Subqueries problem - Cant reuse the table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

```
WITH t as (
SELECT *
            FROM scd p
            WHERE  p.modified_date > FROM_UNIXTIME(1593060230)
                AND ( p.main_id = 1
                OR FIND_IN_SET(1, p.mult_ids) <> 0 )
            ORDER BY modified_date DESC
            LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
),
del as (
SELECT 
* 
FROM t WHERE (status <> 1 AND status <> 2)
),
w_del as (
SELECT 
* 
FROM t WHERE (status = 1 OR status = 2)
)
SELECT w_del.*, del.* FROM w_del,del;
```

How do I achieve this with normal sub queries. I am using MySQL 5.7 and can't use CTEs. Im getting can't reuse table error if I use UNION/sub-queries. Is there a way to achieve this without temporary tables?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can just plug in the code for each alias . . . and keep doing that until you are at the base tables:

```
SELECT w_del.*, del.*
FROM (SELECT t.*
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM scd p
            WHERE p.modified_date > FROM_UNIXTIME(1593060230) AND
                  ( p.main_id = 1 OR FIND_IN_SET(1, p.mult_ids) <> 0 )
            ORDER BY modified_date DESC
            LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
           ) t
       WHERE (status <> 1 AND status <> 2)
      ) w_del CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT t.*
      FROM (SELECT *
            FROM scd p
            WHERE p.modified_date > FROM_UNIXTIME(1593060230) AND
                  ( p.main_id = 1 OR FIND_IN_SET(1, p.mult_ids) <> 0 )
            ORDER BY modified_date DESC
            LIMIT 2 OFFSET 0
           ) t
       WHERE (status = 1 OR status = 2)
      ) del;
```

One critical point, though:  The definition of `t` is using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`.  If there are ties in the `modified_date` column, then the two subqueries could return different result sets.  You have two choices to avoid a problem here:

1. Add additional keys to the `ORDER BY` to ensure that the sorting is stable (i.e. returns the same results each time because the combination of keys is unique).
2. Materialize the subquery using a temporary table.

Comment: My dev env is 8.0 and prod is 5.7. I tried the same way in dev and it wasn’t working. So posted the question here. Do you happen to know why it’s not working in 8.0??

Comment: @user1720827 . . . What does "not working" mean?  That is quite vague.